# what's the best way to store and update the images in Laravel 7? Call to a member function move() on null in laravel when update image?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request, backend

i'm using this way to store the image, is there another way to short this code, and what's the best way when store the image and when update it, cuz this way when i use it to update, i got this error

**Call to a member function move() on null in laravel**

```
$file_extension = $request ->photo -> getClientOriginalExtension();
$file_name = time().'.'.$file_extension;
$path = 'images/';
$request -> photo -> move($path,$file_name);

user::create([
    'photo' => $file_name,

]);
```

could you help me

Comment: This makes no sense. If `$request->photo` is `null`, then `$request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension()` should throw a similar error. Are you sure you haven't made a typo somewhere?

Comment: so, what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First validate the image

Second step is changing the image name

Third step is moving or storing the image

```
$request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
    
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  
     
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
```